# Online stochastic convex optimization.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, stochastic-approximation

I need to find/approximate the argument that minimizes a stochastic convex function $F(\theta, Z)$:
$$ {\arg\min_{\theta}} E_{Z}[ F(\theta, Z) ]$$
Where $Z$ is some random variable (we could assume gaussian) and $\theta$ is a parameter that I can control. The goal is to optimize $\theta$ while sampling $F(\theta, Z)$ as few times as possible, given some termination condition (could be as simple as $F(\theta, z) < a$ for some value of $a$ that I will choose).
For my specific problem $\theta \in \mathbf{R^2}$ and I have a "good" initial guess. I also have a coarse model of $F(\theta, Z)$ but would prefer a generic method. One possible assumption would be that $F(\theta, Z)$ could be written on the form $G(\theta) + H(Z)$, where of course $G$ and $H$ are convex.

So far I have only tested random search, with success but it takes many iterations. Computational/implementational complexity is also of essence.

Any suggestions of algorithms/methods or atleast some ideas of what search terms I could use to find similar problems?

Comment: The separability assumption is a bit much, isn't it? Then you just have to minimize $G(\theta)$ independent of $Z$. // I don't suppose you have a cheap way to approximate $\mathbb E[F(\theta,Z)]$ for a given $\theta$?

Comment: For my application I Think the separability assumption is accurate. Indeed I might just have to minimize $G(\theta)$ independently of Z, however I don't know $F$, $G$ or $H$, and all I can do is sample from $F$. I can approximate $E_Z[F(\theta, Z)]$ by averaging over some number of samples, but each sample is just as costly as sampling for a new value of $\theta$